# how to make the email body some text on new line in iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am sending email from iphone application i want that

in body field right now MyScroe and My Time are showing on same line i want that they should be on separate line each how to show that

```
    NSString * emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score: %d/%d, My Time: %@", numberOfCorrectAnswer, [[[DataManager sharedInstance] questions] count], time];
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"\n\r"` should work in your case. If you wish to change to html (`isHTML:YES`), then you'll have to use `"<br/>"`

```
NSString * emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score: %d/%d\n\rMy Time: %@", numberOfCorrectAnswer, [[[DataManager sharedInstance] questions] count], time];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escape sequences for it. Try `\n` of new line. One `\n` for one line

```
NSString * emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score: %d/%d, \n\nMy Time: %@", numberOfCorrectAnswer, [[[DataManager sharedInstance] questions] count], time];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a line break in this string by using the "\n" escape. Every 
"\n" represents a line break where ever it is added.